# How to change itemview's height to image's height in Recycleview after loading image asynchronously?

Tags: android

My app need to show a lot of images in a list recycleview in order, every itemview's an imageview, and itemview's height should be exactly equal to shown image's height, and images need be loaded from network. It seems no way to change itemview's height after loading image, NullPoint exception is occurred. Is there anybody meet the same issue?

**Here is code**:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
RecycleviewAdapter mRecycleviewAdapter = new RecycleviewAdapter(chData,chName,this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mRecycleviewAdapter);

public class RecycleviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleviewAdapter.MangaImageItemHolder> {

ChJs chJsonData;
String chName;
Context mContext;
int[] screenSize;
public RecycleviewAdapter(ChJs chJsonData, String chName, Context context){
    this.chJsonData = chJsonData;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.chName = chName;
    screenSize = Commons.getScreenSize(context);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(chJsonData!=null)
        return chJsonData.countOfPages();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public MangaImageItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ImageView  mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return new MangaImageItemHolder(mImageView, this);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MangaImageItemHolder holder, int position) {


    String imageName = ImangaFileManager.imageName(chName,
            String.valueOf(position));
    final String localImagePath = ImangaFileManager.localImagePath(MangaReader.website,
            MangaReader.mangaName, imageName, mContext);

    ExecutorService executorService = MangaReader.Executor4Local();

    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            op.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localImagePath, op);

            ((SherlockActivity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    int height =  screenSize[0]*bm.getHeight()/bm.getWidth();
                    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,height);
                    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

                }
            });

        }
    });

}

public static class MangaImageItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageView mImageView;

    public MangaImageItemHolder(View itemView, RecycleviewAdapter adapter) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mImageView = (ImageView) itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }


}
}
```

**LogCat** :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(RecyclerView.java:2537)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2324)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2709)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14339)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4612)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1141)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14339)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4612)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:507)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14339)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4612)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:507)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14339)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4612)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:507)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14339)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4612)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2276)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2040)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1222)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5000)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5463)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do that by applying screen proportional height of the element in the adapter. The function that returns the value:

```
    public static int containerHeight(MainActivity ba) {

      DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
      ba.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

      //get predefined value
      double ratio = Static.PIC_RATIO_VALUE; //ex 4.0

      return (int) (dm.heightPixels / ratio); 
  }
```

In your adapter (onBindViewHolder module) you need to have something like:

```
        //set height in proportion to screen size
        int proportionalHeight UIUtil.containerHeight((MainActivity)mCntx);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, proportionalHeight); // (width, height)
        holder.container.setLayoutParams(params);
```

*holder.container* is the root layout of the element you want to apply the height logic to.

See this [blog post](http://is.gd/8KEjtc), where you have more details on how to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!  I have seen that blog too, there is some difference in my case. All the images will be loaded asynchronously, its height is unknown before.  It crashes because of asynchronous loading

Comment: Have you tried changing the image loading method and instead use Glide (http://is.gd/avcfh4) or Picasso (http://is.gd/wWtuN6)?

Comment: Yes, I figure it out. My way of creating ViewHolder is not right.

Comment: After change to: @Override
    public MangaImageItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_itemview, parent, false);
        return new MangaImageItemHolder(view);
    }, and using Picasso, everything is right now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position)      {
holder.imageviewlogo.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

        holder.imageviewlogo.getLayoutParams().height =     holder.linearlayoutDetails.getHeight();

        holder.imageviewlogo.getLayoutParams().width = holder.linearlayoutDetails.getHeight();

        holder.imageviewlogo.postInvalidate();
       }
    });
}
```